# Asymptotic behavior of a Markov process on the set of $\{0,1\}$-polynomials.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to study the asymptotic behavior of a stochastic process defined on the space of single variable polynomials whose coefficients are either $0$ or $1$.

Letting $\mathbb{B}=\{0,1\}$, I will denote by $\mathbb{B}[x]$ this set of polynomials, and I will denote by $\mathbb{B}[x]_{t}\subset\mathbb{B}[x]$ the subset of such polynomials whose degree is less or equal to $t$. Moreover, given a polynomial $b_t(x)\in \mathbb{B}[x]_{t}$ notice that $xb_t(x)$ and $1+xb_t(x)$ are elements of $\mathbb{B}[x]_{t+1}$: these are the two possible "shifted" version of the polynomial.

Fix two parameters $\kappa,a\in (0,1)$. Define a process $(A_t)_{t=0}^\infty\subset\Delta(\mathbb{B}[x])$ as follows

- $A_0=\delta_0\in\Delta(\mathbb{B}_{0}[x])$. In words $A_0$ is a Dirac on the null polynomial.
- $A_t\in\Delta(\mathbb{B}_{t-1}[x])$ is defined as follows:
  \begin{align*}
  A_{t+1}(b_{t})=\begin{cases}
  A_{t}(b_{t-1})P(b_{t-1})\quad &if\quad  b_{t}=1+xb_{t-1}\\
  A_{t}(b_{t-1})(1-P(b_{t-1})) \quad &if\quad  b_{t}=xb_{t-1}\\
  0\quad & else
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  where, letting $b_{t-1}(\kappa)$ be the evaluation of $b_{t-1}$ at $\kappa$, $P(b_{t-1})=F(\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa))$ where $F:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a decreasing function such that $F(x)=1$ for $x$ close to 0, $F(1/2)=1/2$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x$ close to 1.

Hence, transition probabilities are as follows. $b_{t-1}\in\mathbb{B}[x]_{t-1}$ transitions to $1+xb_{t-1}\in\mathbb{B}[x]_{t}$ with probability $P(b_{t-1})=F(\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa))$ or to $xb_{t-1}\in\mathbb{B}[x]_{t}$, with probability $1-P(b_{t-1})$.

This should be a Markov process, where intuitively, the state $b_{t-1}$ is split in the two "shifted" states $1+xb_{t-1}$ and $xb_{t-1}$. Since each distribution is supported in a new set, there is no hope that there is an ergodic distributions. In simulations,though, it appears that, asymptotically $A_t$ concentrates on those polynomials in $\mathbb{B}[x]_{t-1}$ such that the value $\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa)$ is closer to $1/2$.

This is intuitive, given the definition of $P$. While for polynomials such that the value $\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa)$ is very close to $0$, surely or with high probability the mass $A_t(b_{t-1})$ is transfered completely on $1+xb_{t-1}$ (and viceversa for those who have $\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa)$ close to $1$) the polynomials with $\kappa^{t}a+b_{t-1}(\kappa)(1-\kappa)$ close to $1/2$ are those where the mass is split equally. There is a sort of "balance" on this states.

But how can I show this formally?

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Please give the transition probability of $b_t$ to $xb_t$ or $1+xb_t$ and define $A_0$ properly. Thanks ! Cheers !

Comment: It would be great if you also say what is the application of this process i.e., where and in what context does this process arise ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the transition probabilities, which I though were clear from the definition. Why do you think $A_0$ is improperly defined? There are two polynomials in $\mathbb{B}[x]_0$, namely the constants $0$ and $1$. $A_0$ puts full probability on the constant $0$. You can think that the process starts in the state $0\in\mathbb{B}[x]_0$

Comment: I refrained from giving the definition in terms of states and transition probabilities given the fact that the number of available states for the process constantly grows. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I tried hard to give a sense to **only the definition** of the process. Notations are hard to use, and each time something important is defined, it depends on letters that are not introduced *in advance*.  There is **no probability space introduced**. What is $\Delta$ of something? What is then $\Delta(\Bbb B[x])$. A process is not really a set, (for instance the constant process zero is not the set $\{0\}$), so the notation $(A_t)\subset \Delta(\Bbb B[x])$ makes me not even know what are the values of the process. Then $A_0$ is what? Is $A_0=0$ a.s.? And we have a definiton of $A_t(b_t)$...

Comment: ... And of course the $b_t$ is defined recursively. But there is no start, no $b_0$ or something like this. In the definition, there occurs in the same time a $P$. What is $P$? Does $P$ depend on $t$? Is $P$ constant for all times? The "definition" of $P$ relates it to an $F$.  What is $F$? Any decreasing function, possibly discontinuous, a polynomial? The usage of $b_t$ both as a "state" and as a "polynomial" is hard to digest. And what is that else-branch of the "definition" of $A_{t+1}(b_t)$? Does $b_t$ determine  $b_{t-1}$? And now the question: "How to show *this*...?" What is "*this*"?

Comment: I don't think your comments are useful, but mainly a rant. I think my notation is completely standard. I will flag your comments accordingly

Comment: My comments are trying to improve the quality of the question, it is just a matter of communication. Please do not take them as an offense. I am sure there is some good observation at the base of the question, but it does not reach the reader. Instead of ignoring the comments please answer them. To start please ask the following questions first: What is $\Delta$ in $\Delta(\Bbb B[x])$? We have a process $(A_t)$ with $t$ in $0,1,2,,\dots$ to be constructed - then which is explicitly the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ we are working on? I *suppose* that $\Omega$ is $\Bbb B[x]$.

Comment: If so, an element of $\Omega=\Bbb B[x]$ should be denoted by $b$ - the notation $b_t$ is more than confusing, when used. If you want to denote by $b_t$ a polynomial that should have degree less or equal $t$ then specify this. It is the same story with the $\Delta$ in $\Delta(\Bbb B_{t-1}[x])$. What is this $\Delta$? Where is this notation a "standard" notation? Just mention a source, i will find my way. To see the problem readers may have, i will accept this perspective of processes without probability spaces. We start in $A_0=0$. And at the next step we are either in $1\in\Bbb B_0[x]$ with...

Comment: ... with probability $F(a)$ (or $F(\kappa a)$ i don't know...), and in $0\in\Bbb B_0[x]$ with probability $1-F(a)$. Now what is $F$? Is it the same function for all $t$? If yes, then please introduce it in a preamble, not middle in the story! Can we take one special such function $F$ like [ $1$ on $[0,1/4]$, then $\frac 32-2x$ on $[1/4,3/4]$ and finally $0$ on $[3/4,1]$ ]? If yes, then just fix the ideas. If not, tell us that the problem must allow a general $F$, and the answer should analyze the unclear phenomenon of "concentration on polynomials with value close to half" depending on $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it easy for further analysis, i have simplified in the below,

$$E_{b_1,...,b_t}(b_t) = E_{b_1,..,b_{t-1}}(P(b_{t-1}) (1+xb_{t-1}) + (1-P(b_{t-1})) (xb_{t-1})) = E_{b_1,...,b_{t-1}}(P(b_{t-1})+xb_{t-1})$$
$$ = \sum_{i = 1}^{t} x^{t-i} E_{b_1,...,b_{i-1}}(P(b_{i-1}))$$

$$E_{b_1,...,b_{i}}(P(b_{i})) = E(F(\kappa^{i+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{i}(\kappa))) $$

$$ = E_{b_1,...,b_{i-1}} ( \ \ P(b_{i-1}) F(\kappa^{i+1} a + (1-\kappa) (1+\kappa b_{i-1})(\kappa))  + (1-P(b_{i-1})) F(\kappa^{i+1} a + (1-\kappa) \kappa b_{i-1}(\kappa)) )$$

$$ = \sum_{b_1,...,b_i}  \prod_{j = 1}^i G(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa))$$

If $b_{j}(x) = 1+xb_{j-1}(x)$,
$$G(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa)) = F(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa)) $$

If $b_{j}(x) = xb_{j-1}(x)$,
$$G(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa)) = 1-F(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa)) $$

$$E_{b_1,...,b_t}(b_t) = \sum_{i = 1}^{t} x^{t-i} \sum_{valid \ b_1,...,b_{i-1}}  \prod_{j = 1}^{i-1} G(\kappa^{j+1} a + (1-\kappa) b_{j}(\kappa))$$